# WPF changing position of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, position

do you know any way to assign new position to element after some kind of action(e.g. pressing buton)?

Lets assume that in my WPF I have Rectangle named "Windajo" and I want to change its Y position to be actual_Y_position + 10.

I don't have a clue how to get actual position and only funtion that I managed to change position with is `Margin`. Many people are reffering to `Canvas` but I couldn't make it work.

I managed to change object position with Margin but it's (I guess) distance from MainWindow border and using it is kinda annoying.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
    int i = 300;

                do
                {
                    Windajo.Margin = new Thickness(85, i, 80, 0);
                    await Task.Delay(500);
                    i = i - 20;
                } while (i > 100);

        }
```

If reffering to last position is impossible, is there any way to get a actuall value from Thickness function? For example I want to assign "85" from `Thickness (85, i, 80, 0)`. to some variable. How to do so?

I would like to do it inside code, like the example above.

I really appreciate any help you can provide :)

Comment: Don't use Margins for absolute positioning. Instead, put your Rectangle into a Canvas and set its `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties. In code behind, you would use the static methods `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop`, like `Canvas.SetTop(Windajo, Canvas.GetTop(Windajo) - 20);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access individual components of the Thickness structure like this:

```
Windajo.Margin = new Thickness(85, i, 80, 0);
Thickness t = Windajo.Margin;
double left = t.Left;
double top = t.Top;
double right = t.Right;
double bottom = t.Bottom;
```

If you want to increase Y by 10, you need to decrease the Top margin by 10 if it is Top Aligned or increase the Bottom margin by 10 if it is Bottom Aligned:

```
Windajo.Margin = new Thickness(85, i - 10, 80, 0); // If Top-Aligned
// -- OR --
Windajo.Margin = new Thickness(85, i - 10, 80, 0); // If Bottom-Aligned
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the actual value like this:

```
Windajo.Margin.Left 
Windajo.Margin.Right
```

And to this:

```
Windajo.Margin = new Thickness(85, Windajo.Margin.Top + 10, 80, 0);
```